# Recursive tree traversal

Tags: c, recursion, struct, tree

```
struct Node {
    char*label;
    struct Node *children;     
};
```

I am trying to traverse a tree and print the value/label of the nodes(as defined above) based on the current depth.

Output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JbfU.jpg)

My code:

```
void recurse_helper(struct Node **root, int level, int max_level){
    if (level > max_level){
        return;
    }
    struct Node* r = *root;
    if(r->children == NULL){
    }

    else{
        struct Node *current = r->children;
}
void traverse_and_print(struct Node* root, max_dep){

   recurse_helper(&root, 0,max_dep);

}
```

My code doesn't seem to work properly. Does anyone have a better recursive solution or could someone please recommend how to change my current implementation?

Comment: You need to do a breadth-first traversal of the tree.  You can easily find algorithms to do that (on SO, the tag [tag:breadth-first-search] has over 1000 questions) — they normally involve a queue which is initially populated with the root node, and onto which child nodes are pushed as they're encountered.

Comment: At first I thought it was breadth first too, but I THINK he may want pre-order traversal, with children indented underneath their parent rather than all grouped together.  It is definitely unclear from the example he gave.

Comment: In your example output, if firstkid had a child, would you want it printed out directly below (but indented) firstkid, or directly above grandkid?

Comment: @Stephen Docy That child would be indented and would be located between firstkid and secondkid. So directly below firstkid.

Comment: @Stephen Docy Each level of the tree acts like a linked list which is the reason why sibling is there. So wouldn’t I have to track the siblings somehow?

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick.

```
void printTree(Node *root, int level) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        printf("   ");
    }

    printf("%s\n", root->data);

    for (Node *child = root->children; child != NULL; child = child->next_sib) {
        printTree(child, level + 1);
    }
}
```

It doesn't implement max_level, I'll leave that to you to ad.

Comment: This implementation seems to work. Is there anyway to have a static level counter in the function as opposed to passing level + 1 to each recursive call? Could you please show me how to implement using static counter?

Comment: Hmm, the issue I can think of right off the bat of getting rid of passing in level and using a static is.....you will call this routine many times for the same level, once for each child on that level.  So you would have to figure out how to increment the static variable only when you actually go down a level.  I think passing level in as a parameter is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem seems to be....you are calling recurse_helper() with max_level = 0 :

```
recurse_helper(&root, 0,0);
```

which you stated meant print out the entire tree, however this line in recurse_helper():

```
if (level > max_level){
    return;
}
```

will cause the recursion to stop after the first iteration.  The second call to recurse_helper() will pass in 1 for level and 0 for max_level:

```
recurse_helper(&((r->children)->children), level+1, max_level);
```

So you definitely need to specifically account for max_level = 0.

You didn't describe the erroneous behavior you were seeing, but this certainly seems like an issue.

Comment: Is there another recursive solution that is better than what I did?

Comment: Is it clear how the traversal works? Do you need any clarification?